# Can I do a reduce on a list comprehension into two lists, based on two values?

Tags: python, python-2.5

I've got the following code.

```
sum_review = reduce(add,[book['rw'] for book in books])
sum_rating = reduce(add,[book['rg'] for book in books])
items = len(books)
avg_review = sum_review/items
avg_rating = sum_rating/items
```

What I'd like is this.

```
sum_review,sum_rating = reduce(add,([book['rw'],[book['rg']) for book in books])
items = len(books)
avg_review = sum_review/items
avg_rating = sum_rating/items
```

Obviously this doesn't work. How can I solve this redundancy, without a regular loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two typical approaches to simplify code:

1. Top-down: get the values first and then transpose them with `zip(*iterable)`. It's also cool because it only iterates the collection once:

   ```
   values = ((book["rw"], book["rg"]) for book in books)
   avg_review, avg_rating = [sum(xs) / len(books) for xs in zip(*values)]
   ```
2. Bottom-up: create a function to abstract the operation:

   ```
   get_avg = lambda xs, attr: sum(x[attr] for x in xs) / len(xs)
   avg_review = get_avg(books, "rw")
   avg_rating = get_avg(books, "rg")
   ```

Comment: +1 Answered the question, and I'd agree that the readability lost is not worthwhile.

Comment: I won't use this, but I accept it since it answers the question.

Answer (score 9):

I'd avoid using reduce here. For something so simple use `sum`:

```
sum_review = sum(book['rw'] for book in books)
sum_rating = sum(book['rg'] for book in books)
```

In my opinion this simpler version doesn't need refactoring to remove redundancy. With just two items (`rw` and `rg`) I think it's best to just leave it as it is.

Answer (score 2):

```
sum_review, sum_rating = reduce(lambda a,b: (a[0] + b[0], a[1]+b[1]), ((book['rw'], book['rg']) for book in books), (0,0) )
items = len(books)
avg_review = sum_review/items
avg_rating = sum_rating/items
```

(tested)

Answer (score 2):

You should prefer clarity over optimization.  In 3 years of using Python, I have only had to profile to discover performance bottlenecks twice.  Your original code is clear and efficient.  Compressing the first two lines into one hurts readability and barely impacts performance.

If I *had* to revise your code, it would like this:

```
avg_review = sum(book['rw'] for book in books) / len(books)
avg_rating = sum(book['rg'] for book in books) / len(books)
```

(That's five lines of code down to two with an improvement of clarity.)

Comment: I don't understand why you think the OP is at all concerned about "optimization" or "performance".

Comment: @Karl Knechtel:  He's worried about the redundancy of two loops (hidden in the list comprehensions).  He realizes he can code a single loop explicitly to remove the need to loop twice.  (At least, that's how I interpret his question.  He could be concerned with just repetition, but I many Python questions on StackOverflow boil down to "how can I optimize this?")

Comment: This is exactly what I changed the code to after learning about `sum` in the first reply. And yes, I wanted to reduce two loops to one, but the solutions given so far made me consider otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I solve this redundancy

By making a function, of course:

```
def average_value(items, key):
  values = [x[key] for x in items]
  return sum(items) / len(items)

avg_review, avg_rating = average_value(books, 'rw'), average_value(books, 'rg')
```